# how to add string and list together while printing in python?

Tags: python, string, list

```
user =input("please enter your user name\n")
passwd1=input("please enter your passwd\n")
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('vlmanutslab1',username=user,password=passwd1)
stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command(command1)
output1=stdout.readlines()
stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command(command2)
output2=stdout.readlines()
stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command(command3)
output3=stdout.readlines()
print( "vlmanutslab1" + " "+ output1 +" "  + " " + output2))
```

how to add list and string together ?
I am getting error like can not concatenate string and list together .

Answer (score 3):

You have to convert it into string

One way of doing that is using `"".join()` method

```
print( "vlmanutslab1" + " "+" ".join(output1) +" "   + " ".join(output2))
```

To increase the space between them you can use `tab` as you stated

```
print( "vlmanutslab1" + "\t\t\t\t"+" ".join(output1) +" \t\t\t\t"   + " ".join(output2))
```

Comment: the above works fine but i want the out to be in one line and separated by at least  4 tabs space.

Comment: @ShankarKumar does this help

Comment: what issue i am getting is like this:  vlmanutslab1 and output1 is printed in one line but output 2 goes in second line with proper space.

Comment: @ShankarKumar instead of print can you do repr and show what you got

Comment: i am new to python and i am not aware how to use repr ? so can can i display it in a single line?

Comment: @ShankarKumar  repr( "vlmanutslab1" + "\t\t\t\t"+" ".join(output1) +" \t\t\t\t"   + " ".join(output1))) this provides the output just as print but it shows all whitespace just give it a try you will see

Comment: i am getting this error even after importing import repr " TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: @ShankarKumar try this print(repr( "vlmanutslab1" + "\t\t\t\t"+" ".join(output1) +"\t\t\t\t" + " ".join(output2)))

Comment: same error as above.  only problem is in joining both .join() in single line , all others work good. i tried diff combination

Comment: @ShankarKumar it may not be writing in two lines maybe it is writing in one line only since there is no space  in terminal it is printing it to second .Try writing it to a file and see the file output

Comment: space on the terminal is not the problem. even if i print it without /tab it goes into second line.

Comment: @ShankarKumar try this  print( "vlmanutslab1" + "\t\t\t\t"+" ".join(output1).strip() +" \t\t\t\t"   + " ".join(output2).strip())

Comment: @ Vignesh kalai : thank you.. it works fine now. those were due to extra white spaces..

Answer (score 2):

What you have is a list of strings, you can convert a list of strings to a string by using the builtin [`join()` method.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_join.htm)

Important here is that you call `join()`upon a string you want to use to concatenate the strings together with the list of strings as an argument. That is, the string is added in between every set of consecutive strings in the list (and not at the start and end).

If you want the lines to be newline separated:

```
print( "vlmanutslab1\n\n" + "\n".join(output1) + "\n\n"  + "\n".join(output2) )
```

Though you can substitute `"\n"` for any string you like. If you want them space separated with two spaces between the lists:

```
print( "vlmanutslab1  " + " ".join(output1) + "  "  + " ".join(output2) )
```

Comment: i want them in single line with 2 tabs separated space. but i am not getting this out in that way. print( "vlmanutslab1"    +    "      "   +   "      ".join(output1) +   "       "   +  " ".join(output2))

Comment: i did that but only vlmanutslab1 and output1 is printed in the first line. output2 goes in the second line. please help.